# Impicit conversion warning

Tags: vb.net, string, warnings, implicit-conversion

I am doing this simple operation with a string in VB.NET

I have a string of information called `segmentInfo` looking like this:

`XRT0034:3:89:23`

So I am just trying to get a number out of it:

```
Dim rowNum As Integer = segmentInfo.split(":")(1)
```

And I am getting actually 2 warnings. Both warning are given on the same line of code.

```
Warning - Implicit conversion from 'String' to 'Integer'
Warning - Implicit conversion from 'String' to 'Char'
```

Maybe I could understand the first one, about the `string` to `integer`...but the second one?? I do not understand.

Anyway, can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Split` method takes a `Char` (array) as a parameter, not a string. Hence:

```
.... segmentInfo.split(":"c)(1)
```

Secondly, you need to parse the resulting string to an integer:

```
Dim rowNum As Integer = Integer.Parse(segmentInfo.split(":"c)(1))
```

Do this only when you know that the string is a number. Otherwise, use `TryParse`.

Comment: It would also be a good idea to check that the Split method returns an array with more than one element before trying to use the second element. If segmentInfo doesn't contain a ":", you will get an exception trying to access the second element.

Answer (score 1):

No such overload method `String.Split` which take one parameter of type `String`

From MSDN [String.Split Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx)

You can change to

```
Dim rowNum As Integer = segmentInfo.split(":"c)(1)
```

`":"c` - c is character of type `Char`  [Type Characters (Visual Basic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9cz43ek.aspx)

For converting `String` to `Integer` use `Int32.TryParse` or `Int32.Parse` method to convert string to integer

```
Dim rowNum As Int32 = Int32.Parse(segmentInfo.split(":"c)(1))
'Exception will be thrown if string value not convertible to Integer type
```

Or

```
Dim rowNum As Int32
If Int32.TryParse(segmentInfo.split(":"c)(1), rowNum) = True Then
    'Use succesfully converted integer value
Else
    'Show message about invalid text
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

You must parse it to integer form

```
Dim rowNum As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(segmentInfo.split(":")(1))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim rowNum As Integer = Integer.Parse(segmentInfo.split(":"c)(1))
```